# Unicode Conversion in Python

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

I have 2 sets of what looks like Unicode and i need to convert

```
Unicode codepoint
0x1f602
0x2764
0x2665
0x1f60d
```

to this format

```
U0001F64B
```

any idea how i can do this please?

Comment: i found nothing on the net and im new to Python sorry

Comment: Basic string formatting is a core feature of the language.

Comment: What is the input?  Text from a file?  A list of integers?  Write a good question, get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
j = 0x1f44d

print(int(j))
k = u'\U0001F44D'
print(ord(k))
```

only int and ord were required to make them both int